# Convert column names from number to dates

Tags: r

As you can see my columns names from 2nd one are dates but are not displayed as dates?how can I convert them as dates?

```
data1<-structure(list(`US Shopify + Amazon` = c("Total Net Orders", 
"Total Net Revenue", "Total Net Units Sold", "Order (Shopify) - without case", 
"Net Revenue (Shopify) - without case"), `44927` = c("909", "90361.69", 
"920", "230", "21470.959999999999"), `44928` = c("978", "97577.68", 
"988", "232", "21288.12"), `44929` = c("886", "87583.69", "911", 
"207", "17793.03"), `44930` = c("898", "89988.53", "929", "167", 
"14498.55")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))



# Columns to convert to dates (assuming they start from the 2nd column)
date_columns <- names(data1)[2:ncol(data1)]

# Loop through the date columns and convert them to Date format
for (col in date_columns) {
  data1[[col]] <- as.Date(data1[[col]], format = "%m/%d/%Y") # Adjust the date format accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `format` argument refers to the format of the input so `as.Date` can parse the string. While your names are technically strings, you want to parse them as numeric. So instead of using S3 method for character (`as.Date.character` which is being dispatched now) you want to use the S3 method for numeric by coercing the names to numeric first. Then you need to specify the `origin` argument which is the date for which a value of 0 corresponds. In this case, I'm guessing it's "1900-01-01" (the other popular value is "1970-01-01"). Lastly since R also stores dates as numeric, you have to convert it back to a character.

Using base R:

```
date_columns <- colnames(data1)[2:ncol(data1)] |> 
  as.numeric() |> 
  as.Date(origin = "1900-01-01") |> 
  as.character()

colnames(data1) <- c(colnames(data1)[1],  date_columns) 

data1
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   `US Shopify + Amazon`      `2023-01-03` `2023-01-04` `2023-01-05` `2023-01-06`
#>   <chr>                      <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 Total Net Orders           909          978          886          898         
#> 2 Total Net Revenue          90361.69     97577.68     87583.69     89988.53    
#> 3 Total Net Units Sold       920          988          911          929         
#> 4 Order (Shopify) - without… 230          232          207          167         
#> 5 Net Revenue (Shopify) - w… 21470.95999… 21288.12     17793.03     14498.55
```

Comment: that does not work here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855356/converting-date-columns-from-character-to-dates-give-me-nas-as-result

Answer (score 1):

I have a custom function for similar cases that relies on packages {janitor} and the {tidyverse}.

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

exceldate2char <- function(x){
  
  if(grepl(x = x, pattern = "\\d+") == TRUE) {
    x <- as.character(janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(as.integer(x)))
  } else {
  x <- as.character(x) }      
  x
}

colnames(data1) <- map(colnames(data1), exceldate2char)
```

Comment: but it turned all my cell values to NAs

Comment: It is odd, as all input and transformation are limited to content retrieved from colnames(). What happens if you invoke data1 before applying any changes?