# Converting date columns from character to dates give me NAs as result

Tags: r

Im trying to convert my column names from character to dates but I get NAs instead

```
data2<-structure(list(Type = c("Spend", "Orders", "Revenue", "Impressions", 
"Clicks"), `45292...3` = c("28553.05", "492", "35221.050000000003", 
"4977289", "20570"), `45293...4` = c("30068.25", "478", "30472.83", 
"5405811", "24283"), `45294...5` = c("27220.44", "442", "26138.42", 
"4692552", "20689"), `45295...6` = c("26637.33", "400", "22904.21", 
"4079760", "17514")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


date_columns <- colnames(data2)[2:ncol(data2)] |> 
  as.numeric() |> 
  as.Date(origin = "1900-01-01") |> 
  as.character()

colnames(data2) <- c(colnames(data2)[1],  date_columns)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names have multiple `...` in them, so remove them first:

```
colnames(data2)[2:ncol(data2)] <- 
  sub("\\.\\.", "", colnames(data2)[2:ncol(data2)]) |> 
  as.numeric() |> 
  as.Date(origin = "1900-01-01") |> 
  as.character()

# [1] "2024-01-03" "2024-01-04" "2024-01-05" "2024-01-06"
```